# Gmail API previous page token in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, gmail-api

Is there anyway I can get the previous pageToken in gmail api pagination? Ive already done in next pageToken and its working but my problem is the to view the previous page?

This is my controller:

```
 $newToken = '';


    if(isset($_GET['token'])) {
        $newToken = $_GET['token'];

    }
    $cur_link='msg_inbox';

 $pageToken=NULL;
    $message = array();
    $opt_param = array(

        'maxResults'=>5,
        'labelIds'=>'INBOX',
        'pageToken'=> $newToken
    );


    $msg_response = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me',$opt_param);
    $list = $msg_response->getMessages();
     foreach ($list as $lists){
    $id = $lists->id;
    $msg[] = $service->users_messages->get('me',$id);
    }
    $nxtpageToken = $msg_response->getNextPageToken();
    $prevpageToken = $_GET['token'];

    $wew['nxtpage']= $nxtpageToken;
    $wew['inbox']= $msg;
    $wew['try']=$cur_link;

    $wew['ptoken']= $prevpageToken;
    $content = $this->load->view('tenant/gmail/inbox_list',$wew,TRUE);
    $data['content'] = $content;
    $data['curpage'] = $this->curpage;
    $this->load->view('template1', $data);
```

This is my VIEW:

```
<div class="ibox float-e-margins">
    <div class="ibox-title">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a href="http://localhost/tenant/message/?ptoken=<?php echo $prevtoken; ?>"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href="http://localhost/tenant/message/?token=<?php echo $nxtpage; ?>"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>

        <h5>INBOX <?php echo $nxtpage; ?> </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="ibox-content clearfix divider">
        <div>
            <table class="table messageTable">
                <tbody>
                <?php
                    foreach ($inbox as $row){
                        echo'<tr>';
                        echo '<td class="col-md-2">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks chkbox ">
                                <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <a href = "delete/?message_id='.$row->id.'"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                              </td>';
                        echo '<td><a href="view_page/?message_id='.$row->id.'">' . $row->snippet. '</td>';
                        echo'<tr>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can only paginate from newer to older messages at this time, I'm afraid.

Comment: Maybe you should try to keep a list of pageTokens after each request. Then refer to this list to jump to page you want by using the pageToken that is suitable